# How to use a Abstract Factory Pattern with bounded typed parameter?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I am trying to use Abstract Factory Pattern with the bounded typed parameter with an example as follows:

> CageAbstractFactory.java

```
public interface CageAbstractFactory {
    public Cage<?> createCage();
}
```

> CageFactory.java

```
public class CageFactory {
    public static Cage<?> getCage(CageAbstractFactory factory) {
        return factory.createCage();
    }
}
```

> XxxCageFactory.java (Xxx = Lion, Rat, etc)

```
public class XxxCageFactory implements CageAbstractFactory {
    @Override
    public Cage<Xxx> createCage() {
        return new XxxCage();
    }
}
```

> Cage.java

```
public abstract class Cage<T extends Animal> { 
    protected Set<T> cage = new HashSet<T>();
    public abstract void add(T animal);
    public void showAnimals() {
        System.out.println(cage);
    }
}
```

> XxxCage.java (Xxx = Lion, Rat, etc)

```
public class XxxCage extends Cage<Xxx> {
    @Override
    public void add(Xxx r) {
        cage.add(r);
    }
}
```

> Animal.java

```
public class Animal {
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }   

}

class Rat extends Animal {}
class Lion extends Animal {}
```

> AFP.java (Main class)

```
public class AFP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cage<?> rc = CageFactory.getCage(new RatCageFactory());
        Cage<?> lc = CageFactory.getCage(new LionCageFactory());
        rc.add(new Rat());
        rc.showAnimals();
        lc.add(new Lion());
    }

}
```

At lines `rc.add(new Rat())` OR `rc.add(new Lion())` the below error appears:

```
The method add(capture#3-of ?) in the type Cage<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Rat)
```

It seems there is a type conversion error from `Cage<?>` to `Cage<Rat>`/`Cage<Lion>`

But the problem is the `CageFactory.getCage(CageAbstractFactory factory)` is returning `Cage<?>` which is only decided at runtime by the choice of the `CageAbstractFactory` class that is passed as argument (i.e. `LionCageFactory` OR `RatCageFactory`)

Comment: Can't you write `<T> Cage<T extends Animal>` in method signature instead of `?` ?

Comment: If I do it says, Return type for the method is missing

Comment: Correct typo is : `public static <T extends Animal> Cage<T> getCage(){}`

Comment: Thanks. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `wildcard ?` as in

```
public static Cage<?> getCage(CageAbstractFactory factory) {
    return factory.createCage();
}
```

but use generic

```
public static <T extends Animal> Cage<T> getCage(CageAbstractFactory factory) {
    return factory.createCage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to generalize the `CageAbstractFactory` as well:

```
public interface CageAbstractFactory<T> {
    public Cage<T> createCage();
}

public class CageFactory {
    public static <T> Cage<T> getCage(CageAbstractFactory<T> factory) {
        return factory.createCage();
    }
}

public class XxxCageFactory implements CageAbstractFactory<Xxx> {
    @Override
    public Cage<Xxx> createCage() {
        return new XxxCage();
    }
}
```